# .NET Compact Framework - database

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, mobile, compact-framework

OK, so at the mo we have an MS Access database sat on our server.

It's pretty basic stuff, we have two tables ~7000 records, and the rest of the tables are <20 records. Max of 6 users accessing it. Some links here and there, and there's a desktop front end done in C# by myself that handles all the SQL to and from said database.

I'm developing a data collection app for a mobile device using the compact framework and am wondering about my options - getting .NET CF to talk to Access sounds like it's impossible (from what Google tells me, CF won't play ball with JET), and upgrading the DB to SQL Server seems thoroughly excessive for what we're doing (compared to Access it looks like a bit of a minefield...)

So what are my options? I'm pretty sure we could simplify this right down to some really simple stuff...to the point of wondering if I can just go with some CSV files...but I'm guessing that throws the multiuser capability out of the window (or is there a way of doing it?).

Incidentally, there is zero budget.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the mobile app need to do? and how will (would you like) it to interact with the DB on the server?

Comment: Basically it's inventory control and tracking. So say somebody loads an item onto a truck, they scan it, and it updates the item's record in the DB. It also needs to be able to query the DB for e.g. a pick list. This thing is gonna be working over 802.11b/g and the, ahem, "server" is an archaic steam-driven/clockwork/hamster-on-a-wheel fiasco, so the less data transfer that happens, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Express is free and should suffice for what your trying to do.

There is a KB article to upsize, convert, and move data.

A little more work initally, but Access is pretty awful anyways :) so it would be worth the time.

Comment: Any specific reason Access is awful?

Comment: CF won't talk to Access...or so the internetz says.

Comment: @Tony:  Since SQL Express is free.  Is there really a need for a conversation here?  Obviously since your an "Access MVP" you will not like to hear that, but let's choose VBA over VB.NET too then right?  Come on...

Comment: In this particular situation and assuming IT dept won't have a problem SQL Server Express makes as much sense as anything.   However do please explain why Access is awful.

Comment: I am curious, too. Surely you need a context? For example, Jeeps are awful on a race track, but fine off-road. Just generally awful seems a little broad.

Comment: Will CF talk to neither ODBC or ADO? Seems awfully limiting.

Comment: I believe it's because CF can't run JET...or so I've read, I'm no expert on this area. Is there a way around that with ODBC/ADO?

Comment: Security, scalability, feature set (I get that for a smaller project this may not be as big of a deal), but just because any project is small doesn't mean it will be that way forever.  Why set yourself up for some conversion at a later time, when you can use another FREE tool that offers more.  CLR assemblies, JET replication is garbage.  Years ago it was a fine choice, but if your starting a new project it's a no brainer.

Comment: OK I'm thinking of taking the plung with SQL Server Express just because every other option I've investigated looks like a right royal pain in the ass. Can someone point me to an SQL Server For Complete And Utter DB Newbies Tutorial? Thanks guys

Comment: Matt, you've never answered the question.  Why is Access awful?

Comment: Lol wow... Maybe awful was harsh for a clear fanboy.  Does dead technology work better for you?  This site is for developers.  If you are a developer choosing Access over SQL Express would be an awful decision when dealing with Microsoft projects.  Tony since your a VBA guy as well, if starting a new project next week would you take VBA and Access over VB.NET or WPF and SQL Express? Come on man...

Comment: BTW... That will be my last comment on this thread... I feel like I am arguing with an Apple/iPhone fanboy.  Those fanboys just don't give up and neither will this conversation

Comment: I quite enjoy having a respectful discussion on the merits.  However using terminology such as awful, dead or fanboy are not respectful.